# Makfile: calling a rule at end of rule

Tags: makefile, installation

I need to have `install` and `install-homebrew` targets in Makefile. They should install all files in the same way, except for main directory – Homebrew's target should use mode 750 instead of the default 755.

It's naturall to have one main `install-files` target, that contains everything except the mentioned `install -c -d ..`. But how to construct Makefile so that rule `install-files` is called at end of `install` and `install-homebrew`?

Answer (score 1):

If the two targets really do the exact same thing then it sounds to me like you're looking for something like

```
.PHONY: install install-homebrew
install:          mode := 755
install-homebrew: mode := 750
install install-homebrew:
    # execute whatever using $(mode)
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `:=` assignment in GNU make. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intermediate rule:

```
install: do-install install-files

do-install:
    # Do install here

install-homebrew: do-install-homebrew install-files

do-install-homebrew:
    # Do install-homebrew here

install-files:
    # Stuff to do at the end
```

**Edit:**

As @user657267 pointed out, this may break in case of a parallel build (`make -j...`) because `install-files` may be called before `do-install` is complete. To fix that, you can do instead:

```
install:
    $(MAKE) do-install
    $(MAKE) install-files
```

This will make sure `do-install` and `install-files` are run sequentially.

Note that the sub-makes will have the options you gave to `make` as well: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html#Options_002fRecursion, and you can suppress the output provoked by sub-makes with the `-s` option.

Comment: This might break if make is invoked with `-j`, depending on what the recipes do.

Comment: @user657267 I don't see why it would here.

Comment: `make -j install` might fire off `install-files` before `do-install` is finished, if the `install-files` recipe must absolutely run at the end then it could mean trouble.

Comment: @user657267 All right. I don't know why I thought `make -j` respected the order of dependencies. That would make it pointless. I'll think about how to make my answer parallel friendly. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: `-j` does respect the order of prerequisites, in that make will still start them in the same order, but it runs them at the same time (unless you say they depend on each other).  So you can't actually tell which commands will run or complete first: it's up to the operating system and how it schedules jobs.